# Validate Datpicker Value

Tags: visualforce, date, date-picker

I have a Datepicker field in my VF Page

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
  <apex:outputLabel value="Dealer Purchase Date"/>
  <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block" style="position:relative;"> 
    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/>
      <input **type="text"** id="datepicker" value="{!parameters.dealerPurchaseDate}"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Here I have used **Type="text"**, instead of that I tried **"Date"**
But it makes a lot of differences in the appearance.

[image]

I want the field to be displayed as the first image but validate on entering/submitting page that entered value is of Date type and not a text/number.

Comment: How are you getting Calendar for `<input type="text"`?

Answer (score 0):

Before going to make it more complex, what do you think is it possible for you to bound your date variable with object so we can use `<apex:inputField>`, by that manner VF itself take care of validation and all. '

If your above answer is **NOT**, then let's get into hard part. If you really want the same look and feel, which you seen with the default VF datepicker then there are some tricky ways (which I would personally not recommended because it is dirty way, but if you are ok with that and if you believe if will works for your requirement then you can go ahead), here I'm attaching code reference (Refer method 2) :
http://www.infallibletechie.com/2012/11/date-picker-in-visualforce-page.html

The recommended way to use datepicker with your page is, create a html 5 date input with `<apex:input type="date">`, but it will render the browser based HTML5 Date picker, which is vary as per browser, to overcome that thing and make it more appropriate you can use any third party datepicker JS library like jQuery UI Datepicker or if your page using bootstrap framework then Bootstrap Datepicker. some of the datepicker library comes with prebuilt validation also, which you can use directly. otherwise you can create your own custom code for validation:

If you want to use custom JS for check date validation on page side, refer below JS code, you can modify the code as per your validation (I've used pure JS): you can modify it as per your need.

```
// Check Date for MM-DD-YYYY format
function isValidDate(subject){
  if (subject.match(/^(?:(0[1-9]|1[012])[\- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\- \/.](19|20)[0-9]{2})$/)){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
// Call  function isValidDate('01-15-2016') returns true
```

By above function you can validate the date otherwise there is one more way by which you can do the validation  that is on Controller side, just pass that value into a date variable and if error comes, send the error to page.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution as:

```
<input type="Text" id="datepicker" value="{!DateFieldName}" readonly="readonly"/>
```

This displayed the field as I wanted and by setting readonly it restricted any copy+paste so only via datepicker I can enter values in that field.